# I'm using this code for toggle. How to create multiple toggle using this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').toggle(function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideDown(
            function () {
                $("#plus").text("Hide responses")
            }
        );
    }, function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideUp(
            function () {
                $("#plus").text("Show responses")
            }
        );
    });
});
```

```
<a href="#">Write a responses</a>
<a href="#" id="plus" class="show_hide">Show responses</a> 
<div class="slidingDiv">Test Here </div>

<a href="#">Write a responses</a>
<a href="#" id="plus" class="show_hide">Show responses</a> 
<div class="slidingDiv">Test Here </div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context. Now regarding your question, reading some basic tutos would help you

Comment: the [toggle event handler](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was depecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9

Comment: Yes, to spin further ahead on what @A. Wolff said - create classes instead of ID's in order to do such a multiple [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `id` must be unique, you need to use class instead:

```
<a href="#">Write a responses</a>
<a href="#" class="plus show_hide">Show responses</a> 
<div class="slidingDiv">Test Here</div>

<a href="#">Write a responses</a>
<a href="#" class="plus show_hide">Show responses</a> 
<div class="slidingDiv">Test Here</div>
```

then you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').toggle(function () {
        $(this).next().slideDown(

        function () {
            $(this).prev().text("Hide responses")
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).next().slideUp(

        function () {
            $(this).prev().text("Show responses")
        });
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSbJf/)**

Comment: Please 1 think i need how to change text only hide and show not responses text is it possibly?

Comment: I don't get what you means. Can you rephrase your question?